# I delete cookies file in chrome but i'm still logged in after i restart chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, cookies

Title says pretty much everything. I'm using linux and google chrome as browser. I know that cookeis are stored at **/home/my_name/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies**. I deleted this file but it seems like when i restart chrome and try to browse for example facebook, website logs me in. So I got a little confused as to why websites still authenticate me even if  I don't have cookies file.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105947/i-delete-cookies-file-in-chrome-but-im-still-logged-in-after-i-restart-chrome and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806199/i-delete-cookies-file-in-chrome-but-im-still-logged-in-after-i-restart-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main reasons why your browser ist still authenticating you:
You may have not deleted the cookies (for example when deleting the file while Chrome was still running).
Check that the Cookies actually have been deleted:
In Chrome open the menu, then choose Settings, click "Show Advanced Settings", in the "Privacy" section, click "Content settings". The "Cookies" section should show them (or not).

Not all autologins operate through cookies. Chrome can store passwords and login-pages can still sit in the cache. So try this:
Check that the passwords for the sites in question are not saved:
In Chrome open the menu, then choose Settings, click "Show Advanced Settings", under "Passwords and forms", click "Manage passwords".
Empty the cache:
In Chrome open the menu, then choose History. Now you can "Clear Browsing Data".

Comment: its not about that i dont know how to delete cookies. its about concept. thank you very much.